# Swift UIContextMenu PreviewProvider gesutures

Tags: swift, contextmenu

I added `UIContextMenu` for some view, I want to add some interaction inside `previewProvider` (`ViewController`) (like scrolling, tapping and etc), but any tap inside `previewProvider` is dismissing the `UIContextMenu`. How to allow user interaction inside ?

```
    func contextMenuInteraction(
        _ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction,
        configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint
    ) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        let previewProvider: UIContextMenuContentPreviewProvider = { () -> UIViewController? in
            let previewViewController = TestVC(interaction: interaction)
            return previewViewController
        }
        
        let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(
            previewProvider: previewProvider
        ) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return nil }
            return self.menu
        }
        
        return configuration
    }
    
    func contextMenuInteraction(
        _ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction,
        configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration,
        highlightPreviewForItemWithIdentifier identifier: NSCopying
    ) -> UITargetedPreview? {
        return makeTargetedPreview(
            for: configuration,
            interaction: interaction
        )
    }
    
    func contextMenuInteraction(
        _ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction,
        configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration,
        dismissalPreviewForItemWithIdentifier identifier: NSCopying
    ) -> UITargetedPreview? {
        return makeTargetedPreview(
            for: configuration,
            interaction: interaction
        )
    }
    
    private func makeTargetedPreview(
        for configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration,
        interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction,
        presentReactions: Bool
    ) -> UITargetedPreview? {
        guard let view = interaction.view else { return nil }
        
        let parameters = UIPreviewParameters()
        parameters.backgroundColor = .clear
        return UITargetedPreview(view: view, parameters: parameters)
    }
    
 class TestVC: UIViewController {
    
    private let space: CGFloat = 5
    
    init(interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction) {
        let xOffset: CGFloat
        
        if let interactionView = interaction.view,
           let view = interactionView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) {
            self.contentView = view
            xOffset = interactionView.frame.origin.x
        } else {
            self.contentView = UIView()
            xOffset = 0
        }

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        
        view.addSubview(contentView)
        
        contentView.frame.origin.x = xOffset
        contentView.frame.origin.y = space
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        preferredContentSize = .init(
            width: view.bounds.width,
            height: contentView.bounds.height
            + space
        )
        
        // try to custom add gestures but didnt work
        setupGestureRecognizers()
    }
    
    private func setupGestureRecognizers() {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    @objc private func handleTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("handleTap")
    }
}
```

Comment: The preview view in a context menu is non-interactive. A tap will dismiss the context menu and call a delegate method where you can decide what to do (e.g. push a detail view controller on a navigation stack).

Comment: @GeoffHackworth is there option to do that ? or I need to create own class with all this functions ?

Comment: There is no option. The context menu feature in iOS simply does not support interactive preview views. That is not what it is for. It is a preview of the content being long pressed with a menu of actions to apply to that content (such as sharing or deleting. You could present a view controller as a popover instead but would lose the menu unless you re-implemented it.